# Optim Julia Univariate Minimization with Initial Condition

Tags: optimization, julia

Is there a way to specify an initial condition (which I would hope improves speed) for univariate optimization using Optim in Julia? It seems like this isn't possible reading the documentation as only multivariate optimizations seem to accept an initial condition. I guess I could just specify my problem as a multivariate one, and ignore one of the variables but that's not particularly elegant.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use either Brent or Golden Section search, you can simply use the gradient or Hessian based methods, since R^n includes the case n = 1 for most of the algorithms in Optim. You do have to follow the syntax for multivariate methods and pass a vector.

```
julia> using Optim, Plots
julia> f(x) = -2*x[1]+3*x[1]^2+sin(x[1]*3)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> plot(x->f4([x,]), lab = "Univariate Function")

julia> optimize(f, [2.5,], GradientDescent())
Results of Optimization Algorithm
 * Algorithm: Gradient Descent
 * Starting Point: [2.5]
 * Minimizer: [-0.12943993754432737]
 * Minimum: -6.948989e-02
 * Iterations: 5
 * Convergence: true
   * |x - x'| < 1.0e-32: false 
     |x - x'| = 3.35e-08 
   * |f(x) - f(x')| / |f(x)| < 1.0e-32: false
     |f(x) - f(x')| / |f(x)| = NaN 
   * |g(x)| < 1.0e-08: true 
     |g(x)| = 4.58e-12 
   * stopped by an increasing objective: false
   * Reached Maximum Number of Iterations: false
 * Objective Calls: 12
 * Gradient Calls: 12
```

[image]

Comment: Belatedly- thanks! Any idea how you would do this with Fminbox with a univariate function and initial guess? I've had a quick try but with no luck.

Comment: We've made changes to Optim Fminbox recently, did you make sure to check the most recent docs?

Comment: Just coming back to this. Yes I've checked docs but as I don't have an analytical gradient, and it's univariate, I'm not sure fminbox can help me? happy to be corrected though!

Comment: It's univariate, but that doesn't really matter? A vector with one element is still a vector.

Comment: what about the lack of an analytical gradient? Certainly the example uses one, and when I've tried without specifying one I get an error for not supplying the gradient.

Comment: Where am I supplying a gradient in the example?

Answer (score 0):

You mean for Brent's method and Golden section search? I think the initial condition in these methods is determined by initial lower and upper bounds you set. So providing an initial guess for `x_minimum` would be redundant/wrong from the viewpoint of these algorithms.

For example, in Brent's method the initial value of the estimated minimum is computed to be:

```
x_minimum = x_lower + golden_ratio*(x_upper-x_lower)
```

See the [source code](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/Optim.jl/blob/d9f959480b8ced00572f3140dd85822e74fc0d03/src/brent.jl#L43)

Comment: Thanks.  That's a shame. I use optim in a loop and I'd like to feed the results from one iteration into the subsequent iteration as an update to the initial guess.

Comment: Choose an initial interval size: `x_upper + x_lower` and then use the equation above to find `x_upper` and `x_lower` that give you `x_minimum`. You just have to be careful that the initial interval is big enough to contain the solution you want with high probability.